# Como mudar alguns atributos de um objeto com hooks

Tags: javascript, react, react-hooks

Eu quero atualizar somente alguns atributos de um objeto, esses atributos são variados, uma hora quero atualizar uns, outra hora outros. Segue o exemplo:

```
const [myObject, setMyObject] = useState({
 apartments: 0,
 hoods: 0,
 elevators: 0,         
 heating: 0,
 })
```

Ai suponha que eu tenha o seguinte outro estado:

```
let novaAtualizacao = [{ elevators: 5, heating: 1}]
```

Ai o que eu quero é que `myObject` atualize apenas o que estiver em `novaAtualizacao`. Eu tentei assim:

```
setMyObject(prevState => {
            return { ...prevState, novaAtualizacao }
           });
```

Mas não rolou. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: `novaAtualizacao` é um array, entao voce deveria selecionar o primeiro elemento e em seguida fazer a desetruturação. Algo como: `return { ...prevState, ...novaAtualizacao[0] }`, assim os valores serão atualizados de acordo com os valores em `novaAtualizacao`. Outra coisa, se voce vai ajustar um novo estado, use `setMyObject` e não `myObject`.

Comment: Eu fiz a desestruturação mas só está pegando o primeiro elemento de novaAtualizacao, sendo que eu preciso de todas que estiverem dentro dela

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisa fazer uma desestruturação do valor atual e como o exemplo dado é um `array` de objeto com uma posição é necessário posicionar nessa posição e também fazer a desestruturação (`...novaAtualizacao[0]`) para a mudança do estado, exemplo:

```
let novaAtualizacao = [{ elevators: 5, heating: 1}];
setMyObject(state => {
    return { ...state, ...novaAtualizacao[0] };
});
```

---

Exemplo completo:

```js
function App() {
  const [myObject, setMyObject] = React.useState({
    apartments: 0,
    hoods: 0,
    elevators: 0,         
    heating: 0,
  })
  function handleClickAlterar(e) {
    let novaAtualizacao = [{ elevators: 5, heating: 1}];
    setMyObject(state => {
      return { ...state, ...novaAtualizacao[0] };
    });
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {JSON.stringify(myObject)}
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={handleClickAlterar}>Alterar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">Carregando ...</div>
```